# PayPal does not call IPN on live account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have tested my IPN page many times with IPN simulator and with PayPal test account - everything works good.
When I started use production business account - it does not call my IPN page. I saw logs - there is nothing. I saw PayPal IPN history: and there is nothing in section HTTP responce code. (I guess if it will not be working we will see here 404, but we have NOTHING.)
I made sure - IPN is activated on my business account.
I am pretty sure - this is PayPal account settings issue. Could you advise?

Comment: Can you email me your IPN URL? Email is in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: PayPal IPN Notification URLs [don't seem to take kindly to non-default ports][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509500/532590

Comment: Robert, I emailed you my IPN page.

Comment: Robert, thank you for checking my IPN pages. Unfortunately I cant provide you our business account credentials. Today I got next message from PayPal:
Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/PayPal/IPN
http:/www.xxxxxxxx.com/PayPal/IPN
I have doublechecked - I pass http://www.xxx but PayPal try http:/www.xxx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify what IPN notification url you have set in your production account by visiting:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

If you don't specifiy a url in "notify_url" attribute of your web request form, then above url setting is used to relay notifications, otherwise the attribute you specify overrides the above url setting. So, check what you have specified in the "notify_url" attribute. It should be something like this:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
....
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.croisentoi.com/ticket/ipn.php">
....
</form>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548886/php-paypal-ipn-processing-wont-work/19556695#19556695) link for more information.