# Paypal IPN response on specific port

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm integrating Paypal with CakePHP 3.x. but I'm facing problem to get `IPN` response from PayPal. my site is running on port number `4902`.

My form is

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <div style="display:none;">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mypaypalemail@domain.com">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="18">
    <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="http://example.com/images/logo.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="4.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="21">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com:4902/payments/cancel">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com:4902/payments/ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example:4902/payments/success">
    <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button greenbtn" value="Pay Now">
    </div>
   </form>
```

It is working fine if I run this code without any port number. but if I use port number then I get success and cancel response from PayPal but not get IPN response, I had tried with [Paypal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/), it says me that `We're sorry, URL with port number is not allowed for IPN.` [image: Error on Paypal]

And I can't use any other port. can anyone help me please to resolve this issue?

---Edited-----

Like [PayPal IPN on a port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838871/paypal-ipn-on-port-other-than-80) I am not using `Nginx server`

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PayPal IPN on port other than 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838871/paypal-ipn-on-port-other-than-80)